# Raspberry Pi 4 Target Architecture Cross Linux From Scratch

Tags: cross-compilation, hard-float

I'm following the [Cross-compiled Linux From Scratch - Embedded](https://clfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/cross-tools/variables.html) book. I need to know the following information for the Raspberry Pi 4B:

- Target architecture triplet - aarch64-linux-musleabihf.
- Architecture - aarch64.
- ARM architecture - armv7l.
- Floating point support - hard.
- Floating Point Unit version - neon-fp-armv8.

Is this the correct triplet? If not, what is it or how do I go about finding it out?

I got the FPU version from a [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685787/what-are-the-correct-cpu-fpu-assembly-entries-for-the-raspberry-pi-4) - can anyone confirm if this is correct?

I believe the architecture, ARM architecture and floating point support are correct. Please correct me if they are wrong.

Comment: Pretty sure armv7l should be armv8 as well, the former is 32-bit.

Comment: Ah, yep, you're right. I hadn't realised that Raspbian uses arm7l by default because it's backwards compatible to 32-bit - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101215/why-raspberry-pi-4b-claims-that-its-processor-is-armv7l-when-in-official-specif

Comment: ICYI the 64-bit beta version of Raspbian/RpiOS is fine, at least headless (and probably headful as I don't think we have seen any gripping about it here).

Answer (score 4):

I had to go with the following in the end:

| Name | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `CLFS_HOST` | Host architecture triplet | `x86_64-cross-linux-gnu` |
| `CLFS_TARGET` | Target architecture triplet | `aarch64-linux-musl` |
| `CLFS_ARCH` | Architecture | `arm64` |
| `CLFS_ARM_ARCH` | ARM architecture | `armv8-a+crc` |
| `CLFS_ARM_CPU` | ARM CPU | `cortex-a72` |
| `CLFS_ABI` | ABI data model | `lp64` |

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comment you want arm8 for 64bit machine.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# cat /boot/firmware/config.txt 
# Switch the CPU from ARMv7 into ARMv8 (aarch64) mode
arm_64bit=1

enable_uart=1
upstream_kernel=1

kernel=vmlinuz-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64
# For details on the initramfs directive, see
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=10532
initramfs initrd.img-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's down to specifying neon in the mfpu definition;-

"If the selected floating-point hardware includes the NEON extension (e.g. -mfpu=neon), note that floating-point operations are not generated by GCC’s auto-vectorization pass unless -funsafe-math-optimizations is also specified. This is because NEON hardware does not fully implement the IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (in particular denormal values are treated as zero), so the use of NEON instructions may lead to a loss of precision. "

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#index-mfloat-abi